# std::vector with empty gaps

Tags: c++, std

I'm currently working on game engine as university project for graphics API class.

As I need to load and then throw away resources, I'm using right now a basic vector without possibility to throw away any resource that is already loaded in given vector.

All I can with my implementation right now is to derive every class inside of this vector from `BaseResource` class which has a `bool _empty`

I have no way to  defragmentize this vector.

I tried to create this class i called `gvector` (Gap Vector)

```cpp
template <class T>
class gvector {
    // invariant: _items.size() == _gaps.size()
    std::vector<T> _items;
    std::vector<bool> _gaps;
    
public:
    begin();
    end();
    ...
```

but ultimately I don't want to rewrite any code that already exists.
So my question is , is there any implementation of this in any library ??
Is there a proper name for this data structure??
and what is the best way to implement it ??

Comment: It is called sparse matrix. Boost library has an implementation for the same. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_sparse.html

Comment: Instead of a vector<T> and vector<bool> pairing, your entire gap vector can likely be replaced with `std::vector<std::optional<T>>` where each element in the vector either is valid or not.  But if all you need to do is enumerate via begin and end, why not just use `std::list`.  What other methods do you need?

Comment: @selbie I dont want to use `std::list` because of speed issues. Because I will access it and traverse it lot of times for second, and also I need to be able to have index to given position

Comment: Depends on what's in `T` and if you have control on `T`s structure. Otherwise `std::optional` as @selbie mentioned is pretty simple.

Comment: @T4G2 - you really need to to clarify your requirements.  You originally did not state you needed direct access.  What are all the operations you are doing to do on your collection of T.  How does your game track index numbers into the vector?  More details please.

Comment: _"I need to load and then throw away resources"_ — If you do this only once, wouldn't be better simply to move the not-thrown-away elements into a new vector and then destroy the original one? If you need a quick index-based access, you can provide an additional table that would map indexes to new vector elements.

Comment: Maybe [colony](https://plflib.org/colony.htm) could be of some interest. I saw a [CppCon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBER1R8YyGY) talk about it some years ago.

Comment: @super This colony thing looks great for what I need!, Thank you

Comment: @selbie when I reference any resource I reference it as index in given vector.
Operation i want to do :
add/remove
iteration
direct acces (via [] )
save index out of this data structure as pointer to given resource

Comment: So what happens if you use an index that is inside a gap?

Comment: exception @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: Then either what you have now or colony or a vector of pointers to your objects are all viable options. Consider also std::unordered_map.